# How to get the vendor and product ID of a usb device from /sys/bus/devices/usb/devices

Tags: linux, usb

I have a WiFi adapter plugged into my computer, I can find it's ID numbers by looking through the output of `lsusb`.

```
Bus 005 Device 009: ID 1737:0071 Linksys WUSB600N v1 Dual-Band Wireless-N Network Adapter [Ralink RT2870]
```

This is the only wiFi adapter I have plugged in currently, so this obviously is it. I searched around in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` until I found this path on my machine

```
# ls -l /sys/bus/usb/devices/5-3.1:1.0/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:11 authorized
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:11 bAlternateSetting
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:06 bInterfaceClass
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:06 bInterfaceNumber
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:06 bInterfaceProtocol
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:06 bInterfaceSubClass
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:11 bNumEndpoints
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dec 28 18:06 driver -> ../../../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/rt2800usb
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 ep_01
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 ep_02
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 ep_03
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 ep_04
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 ep_05
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 ep_06
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 ep_81
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:06 ieee80211
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    0 Dec 28 18:06 leds
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:11 modalias
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Dec 28 18:06 net
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Dec 28 18:11 power
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dec 28 18:06 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../bus/usb
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:11 supports_autosuspend
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 28 18:06 uevent
```

By looking at the `driver` symbolic link I see this is using the `rt2800usb` driver. So this has to be the correct entry for my WiFi adapter. But identifying based off kernel driver name is inexact and I would prefer not do it that way. Is there a file under `/sys/bus/usb/devices/5-3.1:1.0/` that can tell me the vendor ID and the product ID of the entry I am looking at?

Comment: Is there `/sys/bus/usb/devices/5-3.1` dir? It should have idVendor and idProduct files.

Comment: @Flexz yes, there is. I don't fully understand why it is there however. Do you know where the reference material for this is?

Comment: Not exactly a reference, but the LDD book have [some information](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/?u=chp-13-sect-2.shtml) on the topic